# Vue.js 'openNav' is defined but never used / 'closeNav' is defined but never used

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When starting the website it shows the errors mentioned in the title.

Here's the HTML part:

```
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer;" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>

    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
      <a href="#">{{name1}}</a>
      <a href="#">{{name2}}</a>
      <a href="#">{{name3}}</a>
      <a href="#">{{name4}}</a>
      </div>
```

And here is the js part:

```
//Vue App
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      name1: 'name 1',
      name2: 'name 2',
      name3: 'name 3',
      name4: 'name 4'
    }
  })
  export default {
    name: 'HelloWorld',
    props: {
      msg: String
    }
  }

  //Navbar
  function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
  }

  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  }
```

As you can see both, closeNav and openNav are used in the HTML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in vue you should define your functions in methods like this:

```
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  methods: {
    openNav() {
      document.getElementById('mySidenav').style.width = '250px'
    },
    closeNav() {
      document.getElementById('mySidenav').style.width = '0'
    }
  }
}
```

then you can call them with `v-on:click` in your code like:

```
<span v-on:click="openNav()" style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer;"
      >&#9776;</span
    >

    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()"
        >&times;</a
      >
      <a href="#">{{ name1 }}</a>
      <a href="#">{{ name2 }}</a>
      <a href="#">{{ name3 }}</a>
      <a href="#">{{ name4 }}</a>
    </div>
```

PS : alternatively you can use `@click` instead of `v-on:click'

Answer (score 0):

The linter isn't smart enough to know that functions you have defined in the global scope are used within the template; it's only considering the JavaScript code and it doesn't see any usage of those functions within the code.

You can silence the error by explicitly defining the functions on the `window` object:

```js
window.openNav = () => {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
};

window.closeNav = () => {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
};
```

`onclick` is archaic; nowadays we usually hook up event listeners by calling [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Examples) on the DOM element.